# Is there a concise way to notate 'There are exactly 482 x, such that Px...' in logical notation?

Tags: logic, notation, predicate-logic

My prof has taught us that we can express the proposition $⟦$there are exactly two entities characterized by $P$$⟧$ thus:

[image]

That proposition looks verbose, despite the fact that it references just two entities. It seems impractical to use such a formula to express a proposition that references a great number of entities (e.g. 482). Is there a more concise way of conveying the number of entities that a proposition references?

Comment: You could shorten it a little by saying $\exists x_i, \forall i \in$ {$1,2,3$}

Comment: There is no concise formal version. By the way, the version you have with #\exists!$ is wrong.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you. It makes sense to me, but we haven't been taught how to use $\exists!$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Your sentence forces the existence of precisely one object satisfying both $P$ and $Q$. Using different variable symbols does not make their interpretations different. The "professor's" version is surely a misquotation. Even after a fair bit of wine I would not write $\forall x_1\dots\exists x_1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, I misquoted him. I've inset a clipping of one of his slides in the question.

Comment: If you have access to the expressive resources of set theory, you can write "The cardinality of the set of all muppets is $2$," or more formally "$|\mathrm{Muppets}|=2$.

Comment: For a concise version, we use everyday speech.

Comment: @AndréNicolas but can you use ordinary speech with a proof system (e.g. natural deduction, truth trees)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard abbreviation for "there are at least $482$ objects $x$ satisfying $\phi(x)$" is

$$
(\exists^{482} x)\phi(x)
$$

The extra quantifiers of the form $(\exists^{n} x)$ can either be defined directly in the metatheory, or viewed as abbreviations for longer formulas.

So you could write
$$
(\exists^{482} x)\phi(x) \land \lnot(\exists^{483} x)\phi(x).
$$

There is also a notation $(\exists ! x)\phi(x)$, which means there is a unique $x$ satisfying $\phi(x)$. I have never seen the notation $(\exists !^{482} x)\phi(x)$, but you could certainly define it in your prose.

Although I have seen this notation less, an [SEP article](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/generalized-quantifiers/) suggests
$$
(\exists_{\geq 482} x)\phi(x) 
$$
and
$$
(\exists_{=482} x)\phi(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_P$ be the set of individuals characterized by $P$ and $S_Q$ the set of individuals characterized by $Q$, $\mid S_P \cap S_Q\mid=482$.

Where $\mid S \mid$ is the cardinality of the set $S$.

You can possibly define these sets as $S_P = \{x \mid P(x)\}$.

Comment: I have downvoted this answer: introducting set-theoretic notation only obscures issues of the first-order logic alone. The third sentence, writing a set as the extension of the concept $P$ (as logicians traditionally phrase it) is well-motivated, but the whole history of set theory is the result of that notation not being any good...

Answer (score 1):

$$\exists x_1, \ldots, x_{482}\left(\bigwedge_{i \neq j \leq 482}x_i \neq x_j \wedge \forall y \left(\phi(y) \leftrightarrow (\bigvee_{i \leq 482} y = x_i)\right)\right)$$

Or, since it's not in doubt that there *is* such a first-order formula, create some ad-hoc shorthand and write 
"$\exists^{482} x\, \phi(x)$ where $\exists^{482}x$ is a quantifier denoting the existence of exactly 482 distinct such $x$", which is kinder to your reader.

Comment: Oh look, Carl's answer says this superscripted-quantifier notation is almost . One point to note is that both $\exists!$ and $\exists\text{-exactly-}n$ quantifiers conceal a universal assertion within them: they are $\Sigma_1$ formulas, not pure existential quantifiers.

Comment: What is a $\Sigma_1$ quantifier?